# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}n a_n=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am having trouble with the proof of this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Question**

Assume that $L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n = L$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You have that $a_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$, but you also want to show that $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? This holds true if $L=0$, but not sure if this is what you want to ask

Comment: @Spaceman I think that $\lim na_n = L$, but it's hard to say with such poorly formatted questions..

Comment: @5xum I see, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Hi Jack, welcome to the site. Can you please reformat your question to make it clear? Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you use the fact that if $a_n\rightarrow L$ and $b_n\rightarrow M$, then $a_nb_n\rightarrow LM$?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the operating properties of limits:

$$
\lim a_n = \lim \frac{n a_n}{n} = \lim n a_n \cdot \lim \frac 1n  = L \cdot 0 = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a_n) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = L$.

**Claim:** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$.

*Proof*

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, then since $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = L$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|na_n - L| < \epsilon \quad \forall\ n \geq N.
$$
Reformatting this, we have that the above is equivalent to the statement
$$
-2\frac{\max\{|L|,\epsilon\}}{n} < \frac{1}{n}(L - \epsilon) < a_n <  \frac{1}{n}(L + \epsilon) < 2\frac{\max\{|L|,\epsilon\}}{n} , \quad \forall\ n\geq N.
$$
That is
$$
0 \leq |a_n| < 2\frac{\max\{|L|,\epsilon\}}{n}, \quad \forall\ n \geq N.
$$
Applying the squeeze/sandwich theorem (or whichever name you attribute to this theorem), since $A/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for any finite $A \in \mathbb{R}$ (independent of $n$), then $a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.